# profile.d script permission denied

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to disable ACPI wake on usb in Ubuntu 20.04
So I created a script in /etc/profile.d

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   110 May 18 00:23 disable-usb-wake.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e
if cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | egrep 'XHC.*enabled'; then
    echo "XHC" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
fi
```

When I start my machine it says permission denied. Why?

Comment: IIRC `/etc/profile.d` scripts are run when a user logs in (more specifically, when a login shell is started), as the user. Has your user permissions to write into `/proc/acpi/wakeup`?

Comment: I could not post here without making an attempt. i'm looking for guidance on how to achieve a simple end, in a paradigmatic way. What are other people doing to stop USB from waking their machines? I've tried setting this in rc.local. I didn't get an error, although neither was the value set. At least by the time I got to it. People accuse systemd of over-reaching. I don't mind, as long as users aren't expected to figure it all out though deductive inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `/etc/profile.d` is being run as the user logging in, so will not have sufficient permissions to modify system configuration. You could add a `sudo` command there, but that would just mean you'll need to type your password again when you log in - this would be annoying and will also not work if the logging in user is not a system admin. Also, it will not do its job if no one is logging in after boot.

There are a few options, including adding `/etc/rc.local` as you mentioned, which was one of the common ways to do this kind of custom "on-boot" jobs before SystemD made the whole `/etc/rc*` thing irrelevant.

But - if you already have `/etc/rc.local` set up with your script, you can just enable it in SystemD by:

1. Make sure `/etc/rc.local` is executable. For example by running `chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`. The SystemD compatibility mode will not work otherwise.
2. Allow the SystemD compatibility mode to be enabled by creating the file `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d/enable.conf` with the contents below.
3. Enable the SystemD compatibility by running `sudo systemctl enable rc-local`

`/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d/enable.conf` :

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next time your system boot, SystemD will run your custom `/etc/rc.local`.

#### SystemD Alternatives

1. Make use of [SystemD tmpfiles management system to have it write what you need during boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Temporary_files). **This is my recommended solution.**
2. See this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049178/suspend-instantly-restarting-editing-acpi-wakeup-with-systemd-service) for some people making SystemD services to do the same thing.
3. I believe you can write a udev rule that disables "`power/wakeup`" when it sees whatever the XHC is (I think its the onboard XHCI USB hub?), as documented here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/usb/power-management.html